# Input Unity не выдает координаты первого нажатия

Tags: unity3d, input

У меня в коде с помощью Action в в новой системе ввода узнается координата тапа(игра для андроид), и координаты первого тапа всегда равны (0,0).После первого тапа координаты выдает верно. Как это исправить?

```
 private void Awake()
    {
        touchControls = new TouchControls();
        touchControls.Touch.TouchPress.started += ctx => StartTouch(ctx);
        touchControls.Touch.TouchPress.canceled += ctx => EndTouch(ctx);

    }

  private void StartTouch(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (OnStartTouch != null)
        {
            OnStartTouch(touchControls.Touch.TouchPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>(), (float)context.startTime);
        }
    }
```

Вот код привязки к событию тапа на экран.

```
 private void OnEnable()
    {
        inputManager.OnStartTouch += Aiming;
        inputManager.OnEndTouch += Shoot;
    }

 private void Aiming(Vector2 screenPosition,float time)
    {

        if(firstInput||(!canShoot))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!aiming)
        {         
                startPos = screenPosition;
                print(startPos);
                aiming = true;
        }
    }
```

Это уже в самом скрипте стрельбы начало прицеливания привязывается к событию нажатия на экран

Comment: Все гадалки и ясновидящии спасаются от жары на море и в данный момент не доступны. А мы ничтожные не видя кода, ничем помочь не можем.

Comment: спасибо без твоего коммента я бы не знаю что делал

Comment: Не за что, обращайся.

Comment: добавил код, но в данной ситуации как мне кажется проблема не в коде, а в самом инпуте ,он начинает считывать инфу только после 2 нажатия

Comment: А причем тут код подписывания на событие? Никаких проблем с тем, что события не приходят ты не описывал. Ты на другое жаловался.

Comment: какой код тогда нужен?к этому больше ничего не относится

Comment: А, так `TouchControls` не ты писал, это какой-то сторонний фреймворк, ну так это надо в теме указывать, не каждый ванга.

Comment: Да,первая тема,извини что неподробно.Touch Controls называется мой Input Action Asset,здесь я его инициализирую просто и привязываюсь к событиям инпута

Comment: Ааа лол, это же новая Unity InputSystem. Я с ней ещё не знакомился.

Answer (score 0):

В общем поискав информацию в интернете и просмотрев форумы, пришел к выводу что это баг самого фреймворка, много людей пишут об этом, еще не пофиксили.